# AADSTS65001: The user has not consented to the requested scope

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying to use the adal.js experimental libraries to authenticate a user and obtain an accessToken for their Office 365 Calendar.
My web page uses implicit flow and JS implementation (not the adal-angular.js libraries).

I have passed in the scope of `https://outlook.office.com/Calendars.Read`. This prompts the user for consent.

Once accepted, the libraries return the id_token to the web page, I then have a button which invokes the `AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenSilent` function which makes the call to obtain an accessToken.

This call results in the error:
`"AADSTS65001: The user has not consented to the requested scope."`

I'm a bit lost at this point, i've tried to pass in other scopes which also result in the same error. I've inspected all of the calls to the oauth endpoints (mentioned [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/8e340607f3dcf9c9132e844797c0a7fa93f0830f/articles/active-directory/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit.md)).

Is this a limitation of the v2 App Model? Or is their something missing here? I know that it mentions that implicit flow in a limitation of the v2 model, however the previously mentioned article seems to contradict that.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the exact error message by using ADAL to authenticate Office 365 graph API, and I successfully resolved it by re-installing my Chrome. Basically using ADAL.js in a non SPA web solution would not work, because the recommended authentication flow for web application is authentication code flow. The key point is not to use IE. The below example contains the reasons which I referred: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-JQuery-CORS